# Scrollbars in TextView

Tags: android, scrollbar

I just didn't want to use ScrollView. So I have a textview with enabled vertical scrollbars.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_service_ticketinfo_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"           
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:text="empty"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_grey">
</TextView>
```

The problem is, that scrollbars are scrollable only for texts, which contain a web-links. For other texts I see a scrollbar, but can't scroll.

I can't explain it. And you?

**UPD:**

Another strange thing:
once I set the text with links, then I can replace it by another one without links and the textView stays scrollable

Answer (score 4):

So I think the problem is that TextViews don't automatically scroll, just because you set android:scrollbars. You have to set the ScrollingMovementMethod.

However, when you use autoLink and links are found, the android framework will set the MovementMethod for you. That's why the behaviour's different.

There are two solutions that work for me.

After we set our text, force the movement method to one that supports links and scrolling.

```
final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
output.setText(content);
// ensure that text will scroll with or without linked text
output.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Or set the movement method, assuming plaintext, before adding text to the TextView. If autoLink detects links, it will change the movement method itself.

```
final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_output);
// ensure that text defaults to scrollable
output.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
output.setText(content);
```

(FYI: I'm using `android:autoLink="all"`)

Comment: This should have more upvotes! You solved it for me after searching this issue for a long time!

Answer (score 1):

add this in your code(may be in onCreate)

```
//textView.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()); 
tv_service_ticketinfo_details.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

and test.

Comment: that's the same, isn't it? you just changed the variable name for TextView

Answer (score 1):

**To get a scroll bar at run time or from code, you may try with following solution:**

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">   
          <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/tv_service_ticketinfo_details"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="150dp"           
                   android:textColor="@color/black"
                   android:autoLink="web"
                   android:scrollbars="vertical"
                   android:text="empty"
                   android:background="@drawable/custom_shape_grey">
          </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
mTextViewPort = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view1);
// Create a ScrollView instance
ScrollView mScrollView = new Scrollview(mContext);
// here mContext would be Activity's context. You may also choose
// mScrollView as a global variable.
mScrollView.setScrollBarStyle(SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET);
mTextViewPort.addView(mScrollView,
    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_service_ticketinfo_details);
mScrollView.addView(mTextView );
```

This may help to resolve this problem.